# How to implement zoom inside colorbox?

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox to view images... Is it possible to add a zoom option inside the colorbox?

File `gallery.php`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // initiate colorbox
    $(".albumpix").colorbox({rel:'albumpix', maxWidth:'98%', maxHeight:'98%', slideshow:true, slideshowSpeed:3500, slideshowAuto:false});
});
```

File `gallery2.php`

```
<a href="<?php echo $album; ?>/<?php echo $files[$i]; ?>" title="<?php echo $files[$i]; ?>" class="albumpix">
    <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt="<?php echo $files[$i]; ?>"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guy (Jack Moore) who wrote Colorbox also wrote a jQuery Zoom plugin (http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".albumpix").zoom();
     $('.albumpix').colorbox({
         'onComplete': function(){ 
              $('#cboxLoadedContent img').wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>').css('display', 'block').parent().zoom();
         }
     });
});
```

The answer is a possible duplicate of:
[jQuery Zoom inside a colorbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553791/jquery-zoom-inside-a-colorbox)

Comment: dint work...i also tried this:

 $(document).ready(function(){
// initiate colorbox
$(".albumpix").zoom({url:'', callback: function(){$(this).colorbox({href:this.src});}});
});

Comment: You can use the Zoom CSS property:
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/
but it's not supported on all the browsers.

Try the following jQuery plugin: Zoomooz
http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".albumpix").click(function(evt) {
        $(this).zoomTo({targetsize:0.75, duration:600});
        evt.stopPropagation();
    });
});`

Comment: i have this gallery page with little thumbnails for each picture downloaded the plugin from http://www.foliopages.com/ hes used colorbox...the thing is once i click on the thumbnail and the picture opens up thru colorbox i must be able to zoom the image opened in the colorbox...nthn seems to be workin :(

Comment: I checked the Colorbox plugin, there isn't a zoom feature.

Comment: dint work :( i have to define zoom rit..hw do i do that?

Comment: You need to download the Javascript file from the jQuery Zoom plugin page: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/
Once you download the file, you need to add it to your HTML file:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_the_zoom_plugin/file.js" /></script>

You need to add the previous line after the jQuery script.

Comment: the zoom worked but it zooms in as soon as i click on the image and i cant zoom out...i want to be able to zoom in and out after the pic opens up in the colorbox :(

Comment: Try this:
`$(document).ready(function(){ $(".albumpix").click(function(evt){ $(this).zoomTo({on:'grab', targetsize:0.75, duration:600}); evt.stopPropagation(); }); });`
You'll have the "grab" effect used here:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

Comment: the earlier one u gave almost worked...i have a colorbox the one u gav jus now didnt work  $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".albumpix").zoom();
     $('.albumpix').colorbox({
         'onComplete': function(){ 
              $('#cboxLoadedContent img').wrap('<span style="display:inline-block"></span>').css('display', 'block').parent().zoom();
         }
     });
});   but it zooms in just as it opens

Comment: im using the correct plugins u said..nothing seems to be workin with the colorbox...m goin nuts...bin sittin with this for two days now :(

Comment: id like to use the wheelzoom its more flexible...http://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/

Comment: my bad ... I was looking into the other plugin.
If you're using Zoomooz, there's a property to zoom out when the user clicks again: "closeclick: false".
You can replace this line `$(this).zoomTo({targetsize:0.75, duration:600});` with any library you want

Comment: hey tanx a lot.. i got it running..used a wheelzoom plugin and called it in the colorbox with oncomplete...:)