# How to make jQuery zoom plugin by Jack Moore work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive

You can also test official demos at http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/ on simple responsive mode on Firefox with Tap emulator, it's just not working and I don't get why.

The code I use is combo with colorbox taken from [jQuery Zoom inside a colorbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553791/jquery-zoom-inside-a-colorbox)

```
$('a.colorbox').colorbox({
    'onComplete': function(){ 
        $('#cboxLoadedContent').zoom({ on:'click' });
    }
});
```

Which works fine on desktop. We tried click and grab modes. On mobile it's just full screen image, beyond phone resolution size and does not move.

update: found on official github https://github.com/jackmoore/zoom/issues/130 the user was trying to add `touch:true` but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up wrapping my code above with `if ($(window).width() > 786) {}` so the jQuery zoom is triggered only on desktop devices and on mobile you just expand image with default method built in every phone (you know, the thing you do on your phone photos, with your two fingers that zooms photo in and out).